# how to define a constructor outside class in java?

Tags: java, syntax, constructor

C++ uses double colon to define constructor outside class. What to do in java?
I have a long program so it would have been better to use the declared constructor outside the class body but i don't know the correct syntax.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple google search reveal this? Downvoting. You can refer how to ask a question by checking http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and how to create an example by reading this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: No, that's not how Stack Overflow maintains its quality - rather than ignore bad questions, we explain why they're bad and downvote them so that others don't even read them.

Comment: besides i haven't found it on google or any books.All the articles were based on c++.So i'm asking is there any way to do it?

Comment: @ASH: if you have not found on google that you can not create constructors outside a class, you either didn't google at all, or should really update both your knowledge of Java, and of "how-to-Google"

Comment: It's an absurd idea.

Answer (score 10):

In Java, you cannot define a constructor outside of a class.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, the idea of defining class members outside of the class body is just ridiculous. You can't do it and you shouldn't need it.

In case it looks like you need it, then your class is doing too much. Just split it into more classes, possibly nested.